# Would urination continue after death?

Tags: human-biology, death

If someone was urinating, and they were to hypothetically suddenly "fall dead" (the brain is unconscious and all muscles / organs are unfunctional), would they continue urinating or would it stop?

Comment: Death of who? The person? The brain? Or the kidney?

Comment: @Superbest well the person of course. In 99.99% of cases I've read, "suddenly fall dead", refers to a person. It seems odd saying "if the kidney were to suddenly fall dead"

Comment: Many organs remain intact (and "alive" in that they can be transplanted) for minutes after brain death.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Moreover, even if they were not urinating at the time of death, they likely would at death, assuming adequate filling of the urinary bladder. There are two sphincters that close off the urethra. One is under control of the autonomic nervous system and the other is voluntarily controlled (somatic). At death, both sphincters will relax, releasing the bladders contents.

Comment: [Related TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoDeadBodyPoops). **TVTropes warning**.